# Remove all non-essential Python packages from Linux system

Tags: python, linux

Before I started using [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/) to manage virtual environments for my projects, I installed all Python packages with:

```
pip install <package>
```

or worst

```
sudo pip install <package>
```

Now that I'm comfortable using virtual envs, I'd like to remove all the non-essential packages I installed in my Linux system (elementary OS, based on Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit) A `pip freeze` returns:

```
$ pip freeze
alabaster==0.7.9
anaconda-clean==1.0
anaconda-client==1.6.0
anaconda-navigator==1.4.3
argcomplete==1.0.0
astroid==1.4.7
astropy==1.2.1
Babel==2.3.4
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0
beautifulsoup4==4.5.1
bitarray==0.8.1
blaze==0.10.1
bokeh==0.12.3
boto==2.43.0
bottle==0.12.10
Bottleneck==1.1.0
cffi==1.8.3
chest==0.2.3
click==6.6
cloudpickle==0.2.1
clyent==1.2.2
colorama==0.3.7
conda==4.3.16
conda-build==2.0.8
configobj==5.0.6
contextlib2==0.5.3
cryptography==1.5.2
cssselect==1.0.0
cycler==0.10.0
Cython==0.25.1
cytoolz==0.8.0
d2to1==0.2.12.post1
dask==0.11.1
datashape==0.5.2
decorator==4.0.10
dill==0.2.5
docutils==0.12
dynd==0.7.3.dev1
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
fastcache==1.0.2
feedfinder2==0.0.4
feedparser==5.2.1
filelock==2.0.6
Flask==0.11.1
Flask-Cors==2.1.2
gevent==1.1.2
glueviz==0.9.1
greenlet==0.4.10
h5py==2.6.0
HeapDict==1.0.0
idna==2.1
imagesize==0.7.1
ipykernel==4.5.0
ipython==5.1.0
ipython-genutils==0.1.0
ipywidgets==5.2.2
itsdangerous==0.24
jdcal==1.3
jedi==0.9.0
jieba3k==0.35.1
Jinja2==2.8
jsonschema==2.5.1
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==4.4.0
jupyter-console==5.0.0
jupyter-core==4.2.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.2.1
llvmlite==0.14.0
locket==0.2.0
lxml==3.6.4
Markdown==2.6.7
Markdown-Editor==1.0.1
MarkupSafe==0.23
matplotlib==1.5.3
mistune==0.7.3
mpmath==0.19
multipledispatch==0.4.9
nb-anacondacloud==1.2.0
nb-conda==2.0.0
nb-conda-kernels==2.0.0
nbconvert==4.2.0
nbformat==4.1.0
nbpresent==3.0.2
networkx==1.11
newspaper3k==0.1.7
nltk==3.2.1
nose==1.3.7
notebook==4.2.3
numba==0.29.0
numexpr==2.6.1
numpy==1.11.2
odo==0.5.0
openpyxl==2.4.0
pandas==0.19.1
partd==0.3.6
path.py==0.0.0
pathlib2==2.1.0
patsy==0.4.1
pep8==1.7.0
pexpect==4.0.1
pickleshare==0.7.4
Pillow==3.4.2
pkginfo==1.3.2
ply==3.9
prompt-toolkit==1.0.8
psutil==5.0.0
ptyprocess==0.5.1
py==1.4.31
pyasn1==0.1.9
pycosat==0.6.1
pycparser==2.16
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycurl==7.43.0
pyflakes==1.3.0
Pygments==2.1.3
pylint==1.5.4
pyOpenSSL==16.2.0
pyparsing==2.1.4
pytest==3.0.3
python-dateutil==2.5.3
pytz==2016.7
PyYAML==3.12
pyzmq==16.0.0
QtAwesome==0.3.3
qtconsole==4.2.1
QtPy==1.2.1
redis==2.10.5
requests==2.12.4
requests-file==1.4.1
rope-py3k==0.9.4.post1
ruamel-yaml===-VERSION
scikit-image==0.12.3
scikit-learn==0.18
scipy==0.18.1
simplegeneric==0.8.1
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.10.0
snowballstemmer==1.2.1
sockjs-tornado==1.0.3
Sphinx==1.4.8
spyder==3.0.1
SQLAlchemy==1.1.3
statsmodels==0.6.1
stsci.distutils==0.3.7
stsci.tools==3.4
sympy==1.0
tables==3.3.0
terminado==0.6
tldextract==2.0.2
toolz==0.8.0
tornado==4.4.2
traitlets==4.3.1
unicodecsv==0.14.1
wcwidth==0.1.7
Werkzeug==0.11.11
widgetsnbextension==1.2.6
wrapt==1.10.8
xlrd==1.0.0
XlsxWriter==0.9.3
xlwt==1.1.2
```

I know some of those I can remove easily with `pip uninstall <package>`, but I'd like to know if there's a simpler way to reset this to the system essential packages only (without risking breaking my system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's no problem at all if the .deb packages were installed via Apt or similar tools, as they pull their own dependencies.

If you did something funky, then:

For every package listed in `dpkg -l`, I would run `apt-cache show $package` and grep "Depends:", "Recommends:" and maybe "Suggests:", and isolate the names of those python-* and python3-* packages.